# Custom devise registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, authentication, devise, inertiajs

I'm trying to make an application with devise auth, but i wanna use Inertia + VueJS instead of Rails views. I'm having a hard time to make this work, so far i made the custom controllers using `rails generate devise:controllers users`

The registrations controller

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  layout false

  # POST /resource
  def create
    super
  end

  protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
  end
end
```

The routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, skip: :registrations
  devise_scope :user do
    post 'sign_up', to: 'users/registrations#create'
  end
  root 'home#index'
end
```

Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    protect_from_forgery prepend: true
end
```

Ruby version: '2.6.5',
Rails Version: '6.0.3.2'

I'm using Insomnia to make the requests, i'm passing just a json with name, email, password and password confirmation. This is the response i had
[Insomnia Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RwTT.png)

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Check the img "Insomnia Response". I'm not able to create a user, it returns me what is in the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you create custom path for user registration, but still use default `devise` controller inheritance on call `super` that use default routes helper in some inner functions.

The simplest way to fix it - use devise instead of create your own routes

Remove that

```
  devise_scope :user do
    post 'sign_up', to: 'users/registrations#create'
  end
```

And change `devise_for`

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  registrations: 'users/registrations'
}
```

Comment: Worked, but it return that email and password cannot be blank. Img of the parameters and the response https://imgur.com/EkrlTCx

Comment: This is because you need to wrap all of you parameters in `user` key, like
`user: {
  email: '',
  password: '',
  password_confirmation: ''
}`